# Copying the first line in the .txt file and writing it to the last line Python

Tags: python

I have a txt file with 5 lines. I want to delete the first line copied after typing the text in the first line on the last line.

Example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

After:

```
2
3
4
5
1
```

my attempt

```
with open("equasisemail.txt", 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().splitlines(True)
with open ("equasisemail.txt",'w') as fi:
    fi.writelines(data[1:])
```

i use this to delete the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read the lines using `readlines` (don't splitlines else you lose line terminator). Then write back the file using `writelines` then write the final line with a simple `write`

```
with open("equasisemail.txt", 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
# make sure the last line ends with newline (may not be the case)
if not data[-1].endswith("\n"):
   data[-1] += "\n"
with open ("equasisemail.txt",'w') as fi:
    fi.writelines(data[1:])
    fi.write(data[0])
```

careful as if something bad happens during the write the file is destroyed. Better use another name, then rename once writing has completed. In which case what can be done is reading & writing at almost the same time on 2 separate filenames:

```
with open("equasisemail.txt", 'r') as fr,open ("equasisemail2.txt",'w') as fw:
    first_line = next(fr)  # manual iterate to get first line
    for line in fr:
      fw.write(line)
    if not line.endswith("\n"):
       fw.write("\n")
    fw.write(first_line)
os.remove("equasisemail.txt")
os.rename("equasisemail2.txt","equasisemail.txt")
```

safer & saves memory. Fails if the file is empty. Test it first.

note: both solutions support files that don't end with a newline character.

Comment: It doesn't write the first line on a new line at the end.
It write next to the text in the last line. I added "\n" to the fi.write(data[0]) code, but I couldn't. 

How can I create a new line at the bottom and have it write there?

Comment: probably because your last line doesn't end with newline. see my edit

Comment: Thank you, just first part was enough.

Answer (score 0):

To edit a file without creating a new file you can save the contents of the file to main memory, then open it in write mode:

```
input = open("email.txt", "r")
lines = input.readlines()
input.close()

output = open("email.txt", "w")
for i in range(1, len(lines)):
    output.write(lines[i].strip() + "\n")
output.write(lines[0])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without creating a new file?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do it in one file? I'm pretty sure it is possible, but it would be much easier to create a new file, rename it, and delete the old file.

Comment: Yes, I have a reason to do it in a single file.
I am logging into a site in my project, after certain actions, the site blocks the email I use for 7 days, so I have to use a new email address. In short, as e-mail accounts are blocked, he has to log in to the new account.
It does the login process with the mail written in the first line of the email.txt file.

Comment: Ok I will edit my answer to make it work for that situation

Comment: output.write(lines[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
After receiving this error, the .txt file is as I want, but I am getting an error.